# Nokogiri check if XML element has a child node

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Given an XML structure similar to:

```
<homes>
    <home>
        <name>home 1</name>
    </home>
    <home>
        <name>home 2</name>
    </home>
</homes>
<flats>
    <flat>Flat 1</flat>
</flats>
```

Using Ruby and nokogiri how would I iterate over the nodes and check if the child element is another element or a text node?

Basically if the child node is another element I need to modify what I do with the output than if it was just a text node.

I need to do this without knowing the key names.

As an example I can do exactly what i want if I check the key name (as I know this have a child element) however this need to be generic and not data specific.

This is what I have by checking the key name:

```
repeatingElements = []
        nodes.each do |element|
          case element
          when Nokogiri::XML::Element
            child_content = map_content(element.children, {})
            if element.name === 'home'
              repeatingElements << {
                element.name => child_content
              }
              content_hash = repeatingElements
            else
              content_hash[element.name] = child_content unless child_content.empty?
            end
          when Nokogiri::XML::Text
            return element.content
          end
        end
        content_hash
      end
```

Im trying to avoid using this: `if element.name === 'home'` as with real data I may not know the key name.

Answer (score 0):

why cant you try a simpler approach,
based off of your sample xml doc, this pseudo code must work.EVERY 'Nokogiri::XML::ELEMENT' has a method called 'next_element' which you could leverage in the following way

`xml_doc.elements.each do |ele|
     #iterate over children in the doc"
     ele.children.each do |child_ele|
          #check if the next element belongs to nokogiri text class
          unless child_ele.next_element.class == 'Nokogiri::XML::Text'
               #do something with child_elements which are not text
          else
               #do something with text element
          end
     end
end`